# How do I symlink the contents of the folder without including the actual folder?

Tags: macos, bash, dropbox

I'm trying to symlink my Library/Fonts directory with a folder in my Dropbox, so that I don't have to keep installing and figuring out which machine has the fonts I need. When I try this:

`ln -s Fonts/ ~/Library/Fonts`

I get this error in return:

`ln: /Users/Username/Library/Fonts/: File exists`

I can't delete the folder because its required by the system and thus won't let you delete.

Comment: Incorrect, you can delete the folder. The system will remake it if it doesnt exist though.

Comment: Not on Mtn Lion you can't.  You get [that](http://cl.ly/JoOi) for an error.

Comment: did you try from the commandline?

Comment: also did you try `ln -s -F` to force the link? another thing you might try is to rename the dir instead of deleting: `mv ~/Library/Fonts ~/Library/_Fonts`

Comment: @prodigitalson, that works, but unfortunately now I'm left trying to figure out why the Fonts don't install when you symlink.  Thanks though.

Comment: I figured it out.  Thanks a lot @prodigitalson

Comment: Coule be a permissions issue or a special bit that needs to be set... not sure. I would take a look at the user template fonts directory and compare. You may need to set the perms on the link target to the exact same thing.

Comment: the OS may dereference it.. you could try creating a hardlink by leaving out the `-s` (which specifies a symbolic.)

Comment: did you manage? OSX seems to ignore the ~/Fonts folder if its a symlink?

Answer (score 1):

Delete the Fonts folder (obviously you'll want to move any files you want saved somewhere else) from your Dropbox directory and then type:

```
ln -s ~/Library/Fonts Fonts
```

Note that you do *not* want the trailing `/` for that last Fonts directory.

Edit to address comment:
You're right that this only links to one /Library/Fonts folder. You might try doing this on one machine and then on the other machine(s), try:

1. Turn off Dropbox
2. Save off the ~/Dropbox/Fonts folder
3. Perform the same symbolic link function as on the first computer (`ln -s ~/Library/Fonts Fonts`)
4. Copy over any fonts that might not be on this machine
5. Turn Dropbox back on

I have not tried this so I don't know if it will work, but it should do no harm.

The other alternative that definitely *will* work is to set up a cron job to copy any non-existent fonts in your ~/Library/Fonts folder to your ~/Dropbox/Fonts folder and vice-versa. If the symbolic link trick works, I think that would be preferred.

Comment: That won't work as I won't be able to set the symlink on other machines.

Comment: That's not really the solution I'm looking for, as I have 3-5 machines and they can change fairly often.  Having to turn off Dropbox and copy over fonts manually defeats the purpose.

Comment: @apermanentwreck: The concept was that you would only do it *once* on each machine. As I indicated, I haven't tried this, so I do not know if it will work.

Answer (score 1):

`ln -s -F` will force the creation of the link removing the original target before creating the link.

Comment: assuming he's using the `ln` that comes with OSX he'll need `-h`, too.  i just posted an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12671686/282638) to this effect.

i did upvote yours since it was long before mine and is technically correct for a lot of users. :)

Answer (score 1):

this method will ***only work if*** the target folder is *already* a symlink.

Using the `ln` that ships with OSX or BSD-derived unixes:

`ln -s -h -F /source/folder/to/use /destination/folder/to/overwrite`

the `-h` is key here. otherwise you'll end up with something like *~/Library/Fonts/Fonts* because it traverses inside that folder. the `-F` alone wouldn't try to overwrite, since it wouldn't see a conflict once it got inside that folder.

relevant portions of *ln* [manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ln.1.html):

```
      ln [-Ffhinsv] source_file ... target_dir

-s    Create a symbolic link.
-h    If the target_file or target_dir is a symbolic link, do not follow it.
      This is most useful with the -f option, to replace a symlink which may
      point to a directory.
-F    If the target file already exists and is a directory, then remove it
      so that the link may occur.
```

---

*GNU coreutils* `ln` users:

if you're using the *GNU* `ln` from the `coreutils` package *(linux, brew, macports, etc.)* use `-T`:

`ln -sTf /source/folder/to/use /destination/folder/to/overwrite`

additionally, with the *GNU* `ln` you *can* replace normal folders. look at its manpage for the `-t` option, use it to specify the parent of the target folder:

`ln -sf -t /destination/folder/to/overwrite/.. /source/folder/to/use`

the trailing `/..` is needed to target creation inside the *parent* dir, leave it in place.